# Angular - Life-cycle: Child component to be fully loaded

Tags: angular, lifecycle

Is it possible for a parent component to be notified for a child component to be loaded especially when it comes to `ng-container` and `ng-template`.
*As in `Yes! I see that you've grown strong, my child!`*

Say we have a component like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <ng-container *ngIf="!showElse; else elseBlock">
    <h1>Hi!</h1>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #elseBlock>
    <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
  </ng-template>
  <button (click)="showElse = !showElse">Show else</button>
  `,
  styles: ['']
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  showElse = false;
  @ViewChild('hello') hello: HelloComponent;
}
```

Is there a way for `AppComponent` to know if `HelloComponent`is fully loaded or do I need a custom solution inside `HelloComponent`?

I'm currently sitting with a less-than-optimal solution (a `setTimeout()` based stuff that I don't like).
Here's what I'm thinking about:
- Add an `EventEmitter` to my `HelloComponent`;
- Use the `HelloComponent`'s life cycle to emit an event during, say, `ngAfterContentChecked`
- Intercept this event in my `AppComponent` and do the thing.

What are your thoughts on that subject?

---

## *Edit*

So far, I've tried what you've suggested (hook to `AfterViewInit`, make use of `@ViewChildren`...) but had no success.
Just to be sure, I tried again without the `<ng-container>...<ng-template>` stuff and simply hiding my `HelloComponent` using the `[hidden]` directive...

By emitting an event during the `HelloComponent`'s `AfterContentChecked` and hooking this event in `AppComponent`, it works like a charm. (see [on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bibrny) )
*This solution is way more classy than my previous `setTimeout`-based one*

Now, the reason I wanted to make use of the `<ng-container>...<ng-template>` mechanic is because my actual component is just a *tiny bit* heavier than the example `HelloComponent`.
If anyone has a better idea to keep using the container-template mechanic, I'm all ears.

Comment: I think that using ViewChildren you can subscribe to the change of the "queryList", https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56344620/3681565) that i dont know why is downvoted

Answer (score 1):

Like you suggested, use an EventEmitter in the lifecycle hook AfterContentChecked() to emit an event to your parent component.  It's straightforward, and makes proper use of Angular's lifecycle API.
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to `AfterViewInit` , but it's not the case always, consider you have `*ngIf` on your child component, then you need to do this.

```
private helloPlaceholder: ElementRef;

 @ViewChild('hello') set hello(content: HelloComponent) {
    this.helloPlaceholder = content;
    // you can check and do your stuff here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ngAfterVIewChecked** in your parent component, that tells the parent component that angular has finished change detection on all children

So if you have 5 child component you can know when all child views are updated but you can't know if a specific child component has been updated