# Angular : load an extrenal JS file script after Component View loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Under my **Anglar 5** app, I have a js script file which I want to **load dynamically after the loading of my component view**,

this is because my script acts with my component template, and need to have the view loaded to run

I have tried this :

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit{
   title = 'app';
   ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.loadScript('http://www.some-library.com/library.js');
     // OR THIS
     this.loadScript('../assets/js/my-library.js');
   }
  }

  public loadScript(url: string) {
    const body = <HTMLDivElement> document.body;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = '';
    script.src = url;
    script.async = false;
    script.defer = true;
    body.appendChild(script);
  }
}
```

But it still loads my js before the loading of my component HTML file. , and this results on the non-running of my script.

(i see it in the body but in reality, it's not working)

My purpose is to load my js file **after my component is loaded.**

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: Test it with a `setTimeout` 5 seconds. It works?

Comment: @Gaspar come on this is too dirty :)

Comment: Yeah, but it's to test only haha

Comment: Just use ngOnInit() instead of ngAfterViewInit() and load the "loadScript()" inside the ngOnInit() { this.loadScript(); }

Comment: `AfterViewInit` is called after `OnInit`. If `AfterViewInit` does not work, `OnInit` will not work too

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`AfterContentChecked` LifeCycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#aftercontent-hooks).

> AfterContent hooks
>   AfterContent hooks are similar to the AfterView hooks. The key difference is in the child component.
>
> -The AfterView hooks concern ViewChildren, the child components whose element tags appear within the component's template.
>
> -The AfterContent hooks concern ContentChildren, the child components that Angular projected into the component.

Another approach:

I solved this a long time ago with:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        doSomething();
    }, 0);
}
```